# Unity Scoreboard: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying so create a scoreboard and I always get the NullReferenceException. It's a simple game where you save your time as your score. The one with the shortest time wins and gets a place in the scoreboard. I'm quite a beginner with unity and coding in general. I use 2 arrays to save scores and names.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ScoreBoard2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float[] scoreboard = new float[3]; //saves highscored in correct 
    order
    private string[] scorenames = new string[3]; //saves names in correct order
    public Text score1Text;
    public Text score2Text;
    public Text score3Text;
    public Text name1, name2, name3;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        score1Text = GetComponent<Text>();
        score2Text = GetComponent<Text>();
        score3Text = GetComponent<Text>();

        name1 = GetComponent<Text>();
        name2 = GetComponent<Text>();
        name3 = GetComponent<Text>();

        if (scorenames[0] == null && scorenames[1] == null && scorenames[2] == null)
        {
            scorenames[0] = "X";
            scorenames[1] = "X";
            scorenames[2] = "X";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < scoreboard.Length; i++)
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score") >= scoreboard[i]) //after GameOver the score will always saved in PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("score")
            {
                for (int j = scoreboard.Length - 1; j > i; j--)
                {
                    scoreboard[j] = scoreboard[j - 1];
                    scorenames[j] = scorenames[j - 1];
                }
                scoreboard[i] = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("score");
                scorenames[i] = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Username");
                break;
            }
        }

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("1st", scoreboard[0]); 
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("2nd", scoreboard[1]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("3rd", scoreboard[2]);

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("name1", scorenames[0]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("name2", scorenames[1]);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("name3", scorenames[2]);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        score1Text.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("1st").ToString();
        score2Text.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("2nd").ToString();
        score3Text.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("3rd").ToString();

        name1.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("name1");
        name2.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("name2");
        name3.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("name3");
    }

    public void LoadMenue()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    }
}
```

Comment: I always get the exception in the update() function where PlayerPrefs is set

Comment: Please, add this information to the question itself.

Comment: Also, if possible, add the whole error to the question.

Comment: Either you forgot to reference one of the `Text` components in the Inspector or you fail to get one of the values from `PlayerPrefs.GetXY`. btw you don't need those `GetComponent` calls in `Start` .. you either have the components already or not

Comment: an easy way to find the problem is to add a breakpoint on the line where the exception gets thrown and attach your Editor (VS or MonoDev) on Runtime. When he hits the breakpoint you can check wich variables are null.